# Not Working Properly Orientation of Flashlight Android Application

Tags: android, android-layout, flashlight

I am creating Flashlight Android App..and facing below problem..Please guide me ...
when i press button in potrait mode Flash light is goes on and when I rotate to landscape mode flash light goes off..

```
 ImageButton imagebuttonon, imagebuttonoff;
    public static Camera cmr;
    Camera.Parameters parameters;

    boolean isFlash = false;
    boolean isOn = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imagebuttonoff = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonoff);
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH))

        {

            cmr = Camera.open();
            parameters = cmr.getParameters();
            isFlash = true;

        }




        imagebuttonoff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isFlash)

                {


                    //if flash light is not on
                    if (!isOn) {

                        imagebuttonoff.setImageResource(R.drawable.onswitch); parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                        cmr.setParameters(parameters);
                        cmr.startPreview();
                        isOn = true;


                    } else {
                        imagebuttonoff.setImageResource(R.drawable.offswitch);
                        parameters.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
                        cmr.setParameters(parameters);
                        cmr.stopPreview();
                        isOn = false;
                    }
                } else { 

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Error");  
                    builder.setMessage("Flash light not available"); 
                    builder.setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss(); 
                            finish();
                        }
                    });


                    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create(); 
                    alertDialog.show();

                }

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

             cmr.stopPreview();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

               if (isOn)
            cmr.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
               cmr.startPreview();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() { 
        super.onStop();
        if (cmr != null)

            cmr.release();
        cmr = null;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        outState.getBoolean("mode", false);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
           }
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
               super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for this, which will also be helpful for others who are interested in creating a Flashlight Android Application, as [described on my blog](http://developandroidskills.blogspot.in/2017/02/flashlight-android-app-source-code-for.html).

I just entered these lines in the Manifest.xml file.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Comment: Remember to outright say that something you're linking to is owned by you if it is. If you don't, it's spam.

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion)

Comment: I've edited your answer to make it blatantly obvious that your blog is... well, yours, as is required by site rules. In the future, please do this yourself; if you don't, it'll be seen as spam, and we've got some pretty harsh penalties for that.